# DrRacket: expected a function after the open parenthesis

Tags: racket

It compiles right but if i try to use the function I get an error:

function call: expected a function after the open parenthesis, but received 1.

```
(define (euclid a b)
  (if (= b 0) a
      (if (= a 0) b
          (if (> a b) (euclid(- a b) b)
              (euclid (a (- b a) ))))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a misplaced bracket in the last line. This should fix it:

```
(define (euclid a b)
  (if (= b 0)
      a
      (if (= a 0)
          b
          (if (> a b)
              (euclid (- a b) b)
              (euclid a (- b a))))))
```

When you have several nested conditions, it's better to use `cond`, like this:

```
(define (euclid a b)
  (cond ((= b 0) a)
        ((= a 0) b)
        ((> a b) (euclid (- a b) b))
        (else (euclid a (- b a)))))
```